# Rtc ds3231 for Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: raspberry-pi2, hwclock

I am trying to install Hwclock RTC DS3231 on my Raspberry Pi 2

Below are os version.

```
NAME: Raspbian GNU/Linux
VERSION_ID = 7
VERSION="7 (whezy)
ID = raspbian
ID_LIKE = debian
```

Step taken by me.

1. sudo cp /etc/default/hwclock /etc/default/hwclock.BAK
2. less /boot/overlays/README
3. scroll to the i2c-rtc section and find the crossponding parameter for me it was ds3231
4. sudo nano /boot/config.txt
5. Added dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
6. Save and exit from nano editor.
7. sudo nano /etc/modules
8. Added i2c-dev, i2c-bcm2708 rtc-ds3231
9. Save and exit from nano editor.
10. reboot
11. sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
12. sudo dpkg --purge fake-hwclock
13. sudo i2cdetect -y 1
14. sudo nano /lib/udev/hwclock-set
15. Code:

    ```
    dev=$1

    #if [ -e /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd ] ; then
    #    exit 0
    #fi

    #if [ -f /etc/default/rcS ] ; then
    #    . /etc/default/rcS
    #fi

    # These defaults are user-overridable in /etc/default/hwclock
    BADYEAR=no
    HWCLOCKACCESS=yes
    HWCLOCKPARS=
    HCTOSYS_DEVICE=rtc0
    if [ -f /etc/default/hwclock ] ; then
        . /etc/default/hwclock
    fi

    if [ yes = "$BADYEAR" ] ; then
        /sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz --badyear
    else
        /sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz
    fi
    ```
16. sudo date
17. sudo hwclock -w
18. sudo hwclock -s
19. sudo hwclock -r
20. After that if I am checking the date and hwclock -r both coming correct but after reboot when I am running date its coming correct but hwclock -r it showing below message

> hwclock: The Hardware Clock registers contain values that are either invalid (e.g. 50th day of month) or beyond the range we can handle (e.g. Year 2095).

Comment: Rohit: please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Nobody has pointed out this to me yet. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @halfer done! By the way, is there a editor manual for SO? I like it and would like to learn more on how to edit correctly.

Comment: @Baduker: I wrote a [suggested editing guide here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341623), though note it is my opinion only, and has not received much community vetting or exposure.

Comment: @halfer Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I make some stuff with Arduino and here is the code:

```
void setup() {
  rtc.halt(false); //setupable rtc
  rtc.writeProtect(false); //setupable rtc
  //!!IMPORTANAT!!----!!IMPORTANAT!!----!!IMPORTANAT!!----!!IMPORTANAT!!----!!IMPORTANAT!!----!!IMPORTANAT!!
  Time t(2017, 8, 12, 10, 8, 50, Time::kFriday); //set time to rtc, then the next line uncommented, for the first time, after time is setted comment the next line!!!
//  rtc.time(t);  UNCOMMENT FOR FIRST RUN THEN COMMENT IT, IF NOT IT EVERY RUNS OVERWRITE THE TIME!!!
}
```

The important thing is, once you set up the time of the `RTC` and after it comments it because if it runs again, it will overwrite it with this date time.

The whole project is [here](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Jhon_Doe/smart-motorbike-db112e?ref=user&ref_id=214435&offset=0).